# ActiveMQ Artemis with message grouping performance issue

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm currently battling with a performance issue in ActiveMQ Artemis, and I'm a bit lost. Here's the scenario:

##### System Overview

I'm running a single ActiveMQ Artemis server with multiple consumers using JMS. The messages are configured to use message grouping for sequential processing.

##### Initial Behavior

Initially the message processing is smooth, and messages are consumed in the expected order, and all the consumers are utilized.

##### Deterioration Over Time

However, after a period of time, I've observed that certain consumers start waiting for one consumer to finish processing a message before starting on a new one even if there was messages available from other message groups.

##### Performance Impact

Given that processing a message can take up to an hour in the worst case, this waiting behavior significantly impacts the overall processing performance.

I'm reaching out to the community for insights and suggestions on potential tweaks or optimizations that could help address this performance degradation. Are there specific configurations or settings that I should be exploring?

Artemis version is currently 2.26.0, but this issue was present also in other versions I tested.

Here's the picture of the issue. Blue lines present message being processed in a consumer relative to time on X-axis.

[image]

##### Tried Solutions

I've already experimented with adjusting the `consumerWindowSize` parameter as well as changing `useGlobalPools` to false, but unfortunately I haven't seen any positive effects so far.

The problem has been present with 2.18.0 as well and the versions we used before that (=< 2.14). I should try to test with the latest version, but since it has been present so long I'm thinking it's likely to be some kind of bad configuration on my part.

Comment: Problem has been present with 2.18.0 as well and version we used before that =< 2.14. I should try to replicate test with the latest version but since it has been present so long I'm thinking it's likely to be some kind of bad configuration on my part..

Answer (score 0):

The basic semantics of a queue are first-in-first-out (i.e. FIFO). Message grouping doesn't change that. This presents a challenge because since messages in the same group go to the same consumer then one slow consumer can slow down message consumption for the entire queue.

Typically slow consumers are configured with a lower `consumerWindowSize` (e.g. `0`). This prevents the slow consumers from prefetching a lot of messages and starving other consumers. However, with slow consumers *and* message grouping I recommend that you actually *increase* the `consumerWindowSize` on the slow consumers. Otherwise a slow consumer may block the dispatch of a messages that can only go to itself and therefore prevent any other consumers from getting messages.

To be clear, the broker will **dispatch** the messages from a queue one at a time to the consumers. The consumers don't have to *acknowledge* the messages (i.e. fully process them) in order for the broker to keep dispatching messages from the queue. There just has to be a consumer that is able to receive the message - either for immediate processing or to store in their local prefetch buffer waiting for the currently processing message to be acknowledged. If the broker cannot dispatch the message to any consumer then it will just wait for a consumer to become available. For example, if it is trying to dispatch a grouped message and the only consumer that can accept this message can't accept it (e.g. its prefetch buffer is full) then the broker will just wait for that consumer to be free. It won't just skip that message and try to dispatch another one as that would violate the FIFO semantics of the queue.

The simplest way to test this would be to set `consumerWindowSize=-1` (i.e. disabled). The broker will immediately dispatch any grouped message to the proper consumer (even if that consumer is slow) and then move to dispatch the next one preventing starvation.

It is also worth ensuring that groups with be [automatically rebalanced](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#rebalancing-message-groups). This isn't enabled by default, but I would recommend it in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Perhaps I shall try once more to play with `consumerWindowSize`. I've tried to change that value and have at least tried values 0, 1MB and 10MB with no effect. I might have tried with -1 but I'm not completely sure about that so I will re-test.

Is there any other option that could affect the situation? And with FIFO do you mean that if there's 100 messages for group 1, after which there comes a message for group 2, then if processing for group 1 has started it would mean that group 2 would need to wait for all 100 messages to finish even if there are free consumers?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I got it correctly, having `consumerWindowSize=0` could lead to a situation where there was long processed message being processed and next message waiting to be dispatched from the same group. Now that message wouldn't be dispatched anywhere until that one message is processed and all the messages after it in the queue have to also wait even if in different group. With larger `consumerWindowSize` however that second message could be dispatched to consumer already even though it's processing doesn't start yet. This would make sense.

Comment: However, I tried to change `consumerWindowSize` to 100MB (104857600) but it seems I'm still having issues with utilizing all the consumers. I have 20 consumers and most of the time only 5-15 are active even though I have ~100 000 messages in queue from >= 1000 different groups.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `consumerWindowSize=-1`?